# Node.js crypto seems incompatible with Openssl c++

Tags: c++, node.js, encryption, openssl

I've been banging my head hear for a while. I have an RSA 2-way handshake between a c++ client and node.js server using the crypto module. Node.js is version 8.

Anyway on the c++ end we have code that does the following:

```
// c++_cipher -> node.js
RSA_public_encrypt(
            payloaddump.length(),
            (const unsigned char*)payloaddump.c_str(),
            (unsigned char *)cipher,
            clusterpub,
            RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
        );
```

And node will correctly decrypt it on it's side with it's private key..

```
// node.js <- c++_cipher
return crypto.privateDecrypt(pem, Buffer.from(payload, 'base64')).toString()
```

However when I load the c++ public cert for the client on the node.js end of things and encrypt some payload...

```
// Node.js -> c++
return crypto.publicEncrypt(cpp_pub, Buffer.from(data), crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)
```

and decrypt on c++ side as:

```
// c++ <- node.js cipher
int rsapemsize = RSA_size(mypem);
RSA_private_decrypt(
                    rsapemsize,
                    node_cipher,
                    plain,
                    mypem,
                    RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
                );
```

I get the following rsa error:

```
error:04065072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed
```

I don't understand why node.js would be able to decrypt but c++ can not. I've checked my pub, pem key pairs a million times and they are correct. I also want to state that node.js crypto looks like it directly binds to openssl c++ libs, so it should be using the same library? It also looks like the implement the same hashing + mgf1 scheme... however node uses EVP methods... not RSA_public_encrypt though it shouldn't matter. Not sure if I can change that on Node or openssl side. Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't know how that happened, I deleted the other question.

Comment: Just use HTTPS.

Comment: @zaph this is not a normal web service. This is used on top of https.